# An algorithm that runs remotely on a huge file

Tags: android, api, android-studio, csv, dataset

I have an Android application as part of a degree project that is based on music matching.
The application controls spotify using the spotify SDK, and receives information using the web api.

As part of the project, I need to implement a recommendation algorithm based on data from certain columns in a CSV file, I have a database.csv file of a million Spotify songs and I am supposed to send certain parameters and the CSV file to the algorithm and it will find the most suitable songs for me from the CSV file (return their IDs to me).

I was not able to understand how it is possible to run the algorithm in real time from within the application assuming that the file itself cannot be saved locally.
**What possible technologies allow me to save the file in a "remote" location and receive from it the output of the algorithm to my application?**
(I think if it exists then there is an API that provides it)

Comment: `I have a database.csv file of a million Spotify songs`. Ok. But where? Which size?

Comment: i have download it from the internet , the size of the file is around 300MB @blackapps

Comment: So now it is on the internet and it is on the Android device? Or on your PC? Or what? And from the internet: is it your own internet site?

Comment: If it is already on the internet then i do not understand your question: `What possible technologies allow me to save the file in a "remote" location `. As 'on the internet' would be 'a remote location' already.